# My cat keeps pooping on my dads stuff because he doesn't like dad. My dad wants to put him down, how can I stop the cat from doing this

Tags: cats, defecation

We got 2 cats around 7ish years ago, and they're both 8. My dad doesn't like the cats and instead only tolerates them.

The first cat he has no problem with. Shes generally well behaved but a bit sharky and only really likes me. The second cat likes to go toilet on my dad's stuff. It only happens every few months but it just happened and my dad says he wants to put him down for it. What can I do?

Comment: I also suggest having a serious talk with your father about how serious he is about his threats to euthanize it.  If you get the sense your father is quite serious, you might want to consider rehoming the cat.  As much as I hate to see it rehomed, I'd hate it even more to see it get euthanized over a very normal problem like this.